# Image to binary returning System.byte[] instead of binary format in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to convert image to binary and then store in database. I have a code to do this and after several Google searches, most answers are like the code I have written. The error I have is that instead of seeing a binary format in my database I'm getting `System.byte[]` as output. I also debugged and got the same thing.
Here's part of the code

```
if (Upload.HasFile)
{
    HttpPostedFile postedFile = Upload.PostedFile;
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
    string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
    int filesize = postedFile.ContentLength;
    if (fileExtension.ToLower() == ".jpg")
    {
        Stream stream = postedFile.InputStream;
        BinaryReader binaryreader = new BinaryReader(stream);

        byte[] bytes = binaryreader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);

        Debug.WriteLine(bytes);
    }
}
```

The result of my debug gives `System.byte[]` as output.

Comment: `Debug.WriteLine(bytes)` will output the result of `bytes.ToString()`. For a `byte[]` that result is the type name. If you want to see the actual bytes, you'll have to iterate the byte[] and output one byte at a time.

Comment: System.byte[] is binary... a binary value (0 or 1) in computing is called a bit. A byte is made of 8 bits (i.e. 00110101)

Comment: Almost certainly, your problems are caused by inappropriately converting your data to a string, as you do in the `Debug.WriteLine` call - but you're not showing the code which attempt to perform the insert so we can't point to where this string conversion is happening.

Comment: It is stored that same way int the database. I only debug because i wanted to see what it was returning. My my db column, i have system.Byte[] stored there

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a byte array to string for DB storage

```
var storedString = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

and get the byte array from the stored string

```
bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(storedString);
```

If you really want to use the Binary format, you can look into the [SoapHexBinary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.metadata.w3cxsd2001.soaphexbinary(v=vs.110).aspx) class, particularly the Parse() method and Value property

Comment: There's no *need* to convert to a string if the database has a decent binary data type.